# namespace and c++/c mixed header

Tags: c++, c, header

The following code explains the situation I encountered:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace ns
{
class pod
{
    const short foo;
    const char bar;
public:
    pod(short f,char b):foo(f),bar(b){}
    char foobar();
};
}
#else
typedef struct pod pod;
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

extern pod* pod_new(short f, char b);//BANG!!!
extern char pod_foobar(pod* p); //BANG!!!

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I can't put the C linkage functions inside the namespace `ns`, or the C client won't find their definitions. When I pull them out of the namespace, the C++ definition won't compile either,all  because of the `pod` solution, which I learned from [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/cpp-objs-passed-to-c.html),it's only a preprocessor trick. And sadly, this trick couldn't deal with namespaces.

What am I supposed to do? Should I throw out all type-safety, and replace `pod*` with `void*`, or is there a nicer solution for this kinda situation? Any advices? Please!

Comment: I suppose this is a cooked down example, but your `typedef` misses a `;`

Answer (score 3):

I'd just give two different declarations for the functions

for C++:

```
extern "C" ns::pod* pod_new(short f, char b);
extern "C" char pod_foobar(ns::pod* p);
```

and for C:

```
typedef struct pod pod;
extern pod* pod_new(short f, char b);
extern char pod_foobar(pod* p);
```

But if this doesn't satisfy you, for C++ you could also have a `typedef`

```
typedef ns::pod ns_pod;
```

for C

```
typedef struct ns_pod ns_pod;
```

and then have the same common function prototype.

```
extern ns_pod* pod_new(short f, char b);
extern char pod_foobar(ns_pod* p);
```

*Edit:* In C the `struct pod` or `struct ns_pod` is an incomplete type, so in C directly you could never do anything that uses the fields or asks for its size. The difference between a pointer to an incomplete type and a `void*` is that you can only assign such a `struct` pointer to another `struct` pointer of the same incomplete type.

```
typedef struct ns_pod2 pod2;
ns_pod* q = pod_new(...);   // valid
ns_pod2* r = pod_new(...);  // a constraint violation! (= compiler error)
```

The second one would need an explicit cast, if you want to insist. This is one of the reasons why casts are frowned upon by many C programmers.

Comment: Doesn't it berak one definition rule? (You define `ns::pod` for c++ and `::pod` for `C`)

Comment: @jens-gustedt Thank for all your response. I don't want my C++ side code be poluted by this mixed header. And could you or anyone explain to me what the relation between ns:pod* and C side typedefed pod* ? I know on the C++ side ns::pod keeps the type checking, but on the C side, does the incomplete struct name really mean anything?

Comment: @Lol4t0, no there is only one definition, C never sees any definition. In C there is only a forward declaration and `struct pod` or `struct ns_pod` is an incomplete type.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself :) by checking the symbols of the obj files with `nm`.

It turns out that the C++ namespaces have no effects on functions with C linkage, therefore I can rewrite the code above like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace ns
{
class pod
{
    const short foo;
    const char bar;
public:
    pod(short f,char b):foo(f),bar(b){}
    char foobar();
};
}


#else
typedef struct pod pod;
#endif 


#ifdef __cplusplus
namespace ns{
extern "C"{
#endif

pod* pod_new(short f, char b);
char pod_foobar(pod* p);
void pod_free(pod* p);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
}
#endif
```